# Store parsable backup of all printed documents

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, backup, xps

What I'm trying to accomplish is to always keep a parsable duplicate of all printed documents, and execute a secondary process for each print.

(i.e.: Be able to parse all text, account for pages, vectors, images, etc).
Processing the document can either be done immediately or deferred (immediately is desirable).

As formats go, any PDL might be suitable, my best guess is XPS would probably be the best bet for a parsable format, any recommendations for other formats are appreciated.

Ideally, I'd like to not mess with the user interaction with the printing (e.g.: print settings page; or create a virtual printer, which could save a XPS and then forward the print job to the physical printer).
Since users might not be tech savvy to either set up/use it properly and/or mess up the process at a later date.

What I'm looking for at this time:

- Documentation on the print process and flow (WDK, PDL, what else?)
- How this could be accomplished, if at all possible; are there any existing solutions?
- Any directions into what I should be looking at.

Answer (score 1):

It's only part of an answer, but rumor has it you can tell Windows to keep spooled documents (right-click the printer, choose "Printer Properties", Advanced, "Keep Printed Documents").

You could enable this, and then create a scheduled task (or system service, etc.) that watches the spool directory and moves all files older than a certain threshold to a more appropriate location for further processing. (The age threshold would be a reasonable way to avoid trying to move files that are currently being written.)

Then you'd have to find a program to convert the .spl files to whatever format you like, or try [interpreting it yourself](http://www.undocprint.org/formats/winspool/spl). It looks pretty low-level but Microsoft does offer some documentation about the [MS-EMF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230514.aspx) and [MS-EMFSPOOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231034.aspx) formats that might be a start.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. That looks a bit too low-level, namely a lot more complex for parsing, since XPS has basically XML for each page along with the embedded images and fonts, that would probably the easiest format (time/budget constrains).